# Stored procedure is not getting right data for sales

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

The point with this stored procedure is getting the right data.

- If the `to_date` in `Discount` table is '2099-01-01' it should overwrite the `sales price` in `book_sales`
- If the `from_date` and `to_date` in `Discount` table is for just a period, lets say From_Date: 2014-02-03 and To_Date 2014-02-05 it should overwrite the other prices for exactly that period.

EXAMPLE: So the correct report for February would then show:

```
+------------+-----------+---------+----+-----+
| 2014-02-01 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  3 |  99 |
| 2014-02-02 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  99 |
| 2014-02-03 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  69 |
| 2014-02-04 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  69 |
| 2014-02-05 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  69 |
| 2014-02-06 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  99 |
+------------+-----------+---------+----+-----+
```

But now its just showing 99,- taken from the '2099-01-01'. This is overwriting everything!

Here is the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Loid] @month         INT, 
                             @year          INT, 
                             @report_source NVARCHAR(255) 
AS 
    SELECT Cast(isa.sales_date AS DATE)                                   AS 
           DATE, 
           BV.name, 
           isa.identifiers, 
                     isa.quantity,
           Isnull(id.sales_price, Isnull(u.sales_price, isa.sales_price)) AS 
           SALES_PRICE 
    FROM   book_sales AS isa 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN store AS BV 
                        ON bv.store_id = isa.store_id 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN discount AS id 
                        ON id.identifiers = isa.identifiers 
                           AND id.from_date <= isa.sales_date 
                           AND id.to_date >= isa.sales_date 
                           AND id.to_date = '2999-01-01' 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN discount AS u 
                        ON u.identifiers = isa.identifiers 
                           AND u.to_date = '2999-01-01'  
    WHERE  Month(isa.sales_date) = @month 
           AND Year(isa.sales_date) = @year 
           AND isa.report_source = @report_source
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is ambiguous

```
                       AND id.from_date <= isa.sales_date 
                       AND id.to_date >= isa.sales_date 
                       AND id.to_date = '2999-01-01'
```

I am not good at handling complex sql queries but give it a try:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Loid] @month         INT, 
                         @year          INT, 
                         @report_source NVARCHAR(255) 
AS 
SELECT Cast(isa.sales_date AS DATE)                                   AS 
       DATE, 
       BV.name, 
       isa.identifiers, 
                 isa.quantity,
       Isnull(id.sales_price, Isnull(u.sales_price, isa.sales_price)) AS 
       SALES_PRICE 
FROM   book_sales AS isa 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN store AS BV 
                    ON bv.store_id = isa.store_id 
       LEFT INNER JOIN discount AS id 
                    ON id.identifiers = isa.identifiers 
                       AND id.from_date <= isa.sales_date 
                       AND id.to_date >= isa.sales_date 

       LEFT INNER JOIN discount AS u 
                    ON u.identifiers = isa.identifiers 
                       AND u.to_date = '2999-01-01'  
WHERE  Month(isa.sales_date) = @month 
       AND Year(isa.sales_date) = @year 
       AND isa.report_source = @report_source
```

*** Try it by changing outer join to Inner join as edited in my response.**

Comment: thanks ill test that out in office tomorrow, today=to hangover for sql.

Comment: I tested this, and now the numbers is showing, but they are showing two times. So from the example its showing:  2014-02-03 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  69  AND  2014-02-03 |  ItemName |  Item01 |  2 |  99

Comment: Error 156, SQL SERVER, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'

Comment: Sorry, just omit the keyword 'Left' before each 'INNER JOIN'

Comment: Now its only fetching those sales that has special prices.. And all others is gone

Comment: Im wondering if its maybe possible to use DISTINCT somewhere? What you think?

Comment: My understanding and experience is very limited. Its really hard to deduce something when you don't have the database to test your query. My understanding says that the distinct can only be applied to one field in a query. Maybe try changing Outer Join to Inner Join. If you are simply getting duplication and the data is right then I'd prefer to do the remaining processing in application (Again its not an elegant and efficient way but it may solve the problem). Please update me how things go. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49459/discussion-between-pareto-and-lebowski)